# Basic webserver supporting post+get (using curl and netcat)

Tags: bash, netcat, jq, nc

Sorry if the question's title isn't clear about the objective of this question.

I was able to make a respond-only webserver using Bash only; when it gets a curl post request, it returns results no matter what the input.

### The post request

```bsh
curl -d '{"Name":"Lorem", "age":"34"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://<ip>:8080/
```

### The server's script (server.sh)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
   echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<h1>Title</h1>$(date)" \
  | nc -l -k -p 8080 -q 1;
  nc -l -k -p 8080 -q 1 | cat - | grep -o '{...\+}';
done
```

In the first time I curl, it returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<h1>Title</h1>$(date)` correctly, but not the `nc -l -k -p 8080 -q 1 | cat - | grep -o '{...\+}';`, and curl exits.

In the second time using curl, it doesn't return `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<h1>Title</h1>$(date)` and now returns the result of `nc -l -k -p 8080 -q 1 | cat - | grep -o '{...\+}';` and curl doesn't exit.

The idea is to process the input from curl (using `nc -l -k -p 8080 -q 1 | cat - | grep -o '{...\+}';` + `jq`) but also to respond and then close curl/the connection.

Comment: Another issue is that, when using `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<h1>Title</h1><p>$(date)</p>`, it doesn't return `<p>date</p>` but only the date. It seems that it returns nothing that is after `$(date)`.